# Regular expression lookahead in powershell behaving weirdly

Tags: regex, string, powershell, logging

I'll be the first to admit I'm not the best regex writer. I'm trying to parse log files in powershell. The log files start with a date time stamp, and can be multiline. An example is as follows:

```
2017-01-10T17:52:24.224-05:00 DEBUG (0EC3-018C) < ThisIsAClassName> [blah] log lines are here
     this is an addition to the previous line
     So is this at 2017-01     
2017-01-10T17:52:26.224-05:00 DEBUG (0EC3-018C) < ThisIsADiffClassName> [blah] log lines are here
```

My regular expression looks like this

```
Timestamp         = "\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}"
Anything          = "[.|\w]"
NegativeLookahead = "(?!(" + Timestamp + "))"
FullRegex         = Timestamp + Anything + NegativeLookahead
```

This gives me exactly the input. What am I doing wrong in order to split the lines by their timestamps?

Comment: Do you have to *match*? You could split with `"(?m)^(?=" + Timestamp + ")"`

Comment: `[.|\w]` looks wrong, it doesn't match "anything", it matches only word characters, literal dot symbol, literal pipe symbol.

Comment: And only a single occurrence of that.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That worked perfectly! Would you care to add it as an answer so I can accept and give you credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you deal with multiline contents. In this case, it is much easier to *split* rather than *match*:

```
"(?m)^(?=" + Timestamp + ")"
```

Or, to avoid the empty element at the start, add `(?!\A)` lookahead before or after `^`:

```
"(?m)(?!\A)^(?=" + Timestamp + ")"
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fm%29%28%3F!%5CA%29%5E%28%3F%3D%5Cd%7B4%7D-%5Cd%7B2%7D-%5Cd%7B2%7DT%5Cd%7B2%7D%3A%5Cd%7B2%7D%3A%5Cd%7B2%7D%5C.%5Cd%7B3%7D%29&i=2017-01-10T17%3A52%3A24.224-05%3A00%20DEBUG%20%280EC3-018C%29%20%3C%20ThisIsAClassName%3E%20%5Bblah%5D%20log%20lines%20are%20here%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20this%20is%20an%20addition%20to%20the%20previous%20line%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20So%20is%20this%20at%202017-01%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A2017-01-10T17%3A52%3A26.224-05%3A00%20DEBUG%20%280EC3-018C%29%20%3C%20ThisIsADiffClassName%3E%20%5Bblah%5D%20log%20lines%20are%20here)

[image]

This will look like `(?m)^(?=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3})` in the end and will match any start-of-line position (`(?m)` multiline modifier will make `^` match start of a line rather than the whole string) that is followed with a timestamp pattern *but* the timestamp text won't get consumed (=won't be part of the match value and will thus be present in the split text) as it is used inside a `(?=...)` positive lookahead construct.